Is it a bug in the review queues audit?
When I made a review on this question (Bit packing of groups of n repeated bits in a 32-bit word, compact to 1 bit per group), I noticed that the question is tagged with ms-word (this was one filter of the review).
I wanted only comment with a question on why is it tagged with this specific one. I clicked on "Share feedback" and "Submit", then got the message that review audit failed.
On the reviewed question after that, the ms-word tag was no longer seen.
Is it a bug or I did something not in the required way?

Review audit honeypot messes with tags; leads to wrong comments left

Audits get the tag from your filter to "mask" themselves. Yes, this leads to a lot of failed audits for the stupid reason of "reviewer correctly identified the tag was wrong".

If you filter by tags, any time you see a weirdly tagged question, just make sure you open the question on another page to check it. Very likely it's going to be an audit, which you can skip safely. And for what it's worth, if you find a question badly tagged, better than wasting time in comments is to simply edit the question. Particularly if it's a question from a new user (as you'd find in the first-questions queue), as they are more likely to tag incorrectly.

@yivi I hate the "bypass the review system in order to review properly" advice. The review should have all the information needed to process it. But moreover, I hate that we have to do that because the reviews are actively lying to people then going "lol, gotcha, you freak - you're not reviewing this lie I gave to you properly".

I understand your point of view, @VLAZ, but I don't fully agree. Audits are merely to test if reviewers are paying attention. From my point of view, this is no "cheating", but simply making sure one is paying attention to the correct signals, and handling things in the appropriate way to the environment where one is in. Reviews are not a gain that you "win" by "cheating", so you simply do it, and make sure you are still paying attention, or not.

Thanks for everyone these comments made absolutely clear for me what happened. I have never thought of that.

@VLAZ you hating it changes nothing though. Nor has hating it on a large scale made any kind of difference in over a decade. It's still the same slop. So stop hating and start avoiding.

Goooood.... Your hate has made you powerful.

Lord Vlazidious, the villain of the new upcoming trilogy.

"Can't be worse than the last one," he said, radiating undeserved optimism.
